# How to space children evenly horizontally in css

Tags: css

[image: desired effect]

I have included the effect I want to achieve in the image.

The container div might change width to some extent. The children should have uniform gutters between them and each other and the left and right sides.

I noticed that margins combine. I'm not sure if there's a way to say "minimum-margin" or if there's a way to say "spread out".

One lucky thing is that there will be 6 child elements always. (Or *n* but it will be fixed)

I am using bootstrap in this case. I will investigate the row / column feature. But I'd rather not depend on it. I'd rather find a way that works in non-bootstrap projects as well b/c that would be a more portable technique for me to learn.

**Is there a way to do this without introducing structure just for layout? In other words, is there a rule only solution?**

```css
.phase .float-right {
  float: right;
}

.phase .image-carousel {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height: 175px;
  width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: orange;
}

.phase .image-carousel .circle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: calc(0.5vh + 20px);
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.arrow-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 26.0px 15px 0;
  border-color: transparent #000000 transparent transparent;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.arrow-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 26.0px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000000;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.phase .image-carousel .thumbnail {
  float: left;
  top: calc(0.5vh - 100px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase angular-animate" ng-class="color($index)" ng-repeat="phase in phases">
  <div class="float-right">
    <div class="image-carousel">
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/green.png" />
      </div>
      
          <span class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/green.png" />
          </span>
          <span class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/green.png" />
          </span>
          <span class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/green.png" />
          </span>
      <div class="circle">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can include a margin-right property, and if you want to center everything within the container, you can put a `text-align:center;` in the container's style

Comment: Please add related code.

Comment: @AlexChar, done thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will something like this be a good start?

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px 2%;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

This one might be even better...

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container:before {
    content: "";
    float: left;
    width: 4.5454%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: -0px;
}
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 18.1818%;
    min-width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 0;
}
.item {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><div class="item"></div></div>
    <div class="wrapper"><div class="item"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also add media query's to control the gutter and item size when screen get smaller/bigger (supported by IE9).

Answer (score 8):

> The children should have uniform gutters between them and each other and the left and right sides.

You can use the CSS [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to organize your layout.

Here is a quick example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper.around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.wrapper.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>justify-content: space-around</h1>

<div class="wrapper around">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

</div>

<h1>justify-content: space-between</h1>

<div class="wrapper between">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

  <img class="item" src="http://dummyimage.com/100">

</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, but we must support IE9 :( I'll edit my question. This makes me sad b/c this was *THE* answer.

Comment: @toddmo you are right, the problem of this solution is that it's only supported by modern browers! but at least you learnt something new! i recommend reading more about it!

Comment: Up-voted and I did read your article! Can't wait for MS to get with the program! These new features are great :)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare margin-left on the child elements. Adjust the margin-left until the spacing is equal.

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
position:relative;
}
.item{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
background-color:white;
width:15%;
height:80px;
margin:10px 0;
margin-left:1.44%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What happens when the width of the container changes as the user re-sizes the view port?

Comment: It's percentage widths so the boxes will remain on the same line and the margins will maintain proportion. The height is 80px so the boxes themselves won't be in proportion, but that will be sorted if you use images instead of divs. Otherwise use a script to make the heights the same as the width.